# If I am opening an IRA can I put 2x the limit in and say half is for 2019 and the other half is 2020?

Tags: ira

I am finally looking to invest and have some cash on hand over my emergency fund. I do not have an IRA but am contributing to my 401K. I opened a betterment account investing in ETFs for general investing, but have heard about IRAs for a long time. I qualify for IRAs and am wondering if I should invest my extra cash there. If I choose to can i put in 12,000 on Jan 1, 2020 and say 6,000 is from 2019 and 6,000 is from 2020? I read that the last day to put money into an IRA is the tax deadline of the next year.

Comment: If you have the cash on hand now, open the IRA in 2019, deposit $6,000 now, and wait until Jan 1 to deposit the other $6,000. Problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Not yet

You'll have to wait til January 1 2020 to do both in the same sitting.  They'll be characterized as two contributions; i.e. two $6000 deposits (say) not one $12,000 deposit.

You are allowed to make an IRA deposit anytime from January 1 of that year to Tax Day (nom. April 15) of the next year.   So you have a 3-1/2 month overlap from January to Mid-April where you can declare an IRA contribution to be either year.

- You can make a 2019 IRA contribution up until April 15 2020.
- You can make a 2020 IRA contribution from Jan 1 2020 to April 15 2021.